# java script onclick function not working

Tags: javascript

```
<title>Javascript</title>
<script>
function buttonreport(id,name,address){
    var userid ="Id:"+id;
    var username="Name :"+name+"\n";
    var useraddress ="Address:"+address+"\n";
    alert(userid+username+useraddress);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
ID:<input type="text" name="id"/><br/>
NAME:<input type="text" name="name"/><br/>
ADDRESS:<input type="text" name="address"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="buttonreport(this.id,this.name,this.address)"/>

</body>
```

**now its working but output shows as id:name:address no entered values are displayed**

Comment: your "alret" should be "alert"

Answer (score 2):

You spelled alert wrong in your script

Answer (score 0):

I'm not JS expert, but maybe You need `<form>` tags around submit form. You could also just use `getelementbyid`.

Answer (score 0):

your `alret` should be `alert`. now it works :)

```
<title>Javascript</title>
<script>
function buttonreport(id,name,address){
    var userid ="Id:"+id;
    var username="Name :"+name+"\n";
    var useraddress ="Address:"+address+"\n";
    alert(userid+username+useraddress);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
ID:<input type="text" name="id"/><br/>
NAME:<input type="text" name="name"/><br/>
ADDRESS:<input type="text" name="address"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="buttonreport(this.id,this.name,this.address)"/>
```

Comment: now its working but output shows as id:name:address no entered values are displayed